# Custom Component not correcly loaded inside mat-tab (Angular Material)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-template

First of all, I'm new at Angular, I tought I understood how it globally works but I'm facing my first big issue.

I have a custom mat-tab-group (using Angular Material v7, Angular 7) where I want to inject custom components. In these custom components, I will make some API calls and custom html to display it.

I've been looking on several forums but I did not find any answers (one of them is maybe to use navbar instead of mat-tab-group with routing) but I would really like to know first why it's not working.
I have implemented some custom components (the html is displaying fine, the API calls are doig fine), but when I try to manipulate the html of the active tab, an NullReferenceException happens.

So first, here is the html with the mat-tab-group :

```html
<mat-tab-group id="tabGroupNav" animationDuration="1000ms" mat-stretch-tabs="always" dynamicHeight>
<mat-tab class="tabHome_nav">
<ng-template mat-tab-label>
  <mat-icon class="icon_Nav">home</mat-icon>
  NearyFeed
 </ng-template>
<app-events-feed></app-events-feed>
</mat-tab>

<mat-tab class="tabHome_nav">
 <ng-template mat-tab-label>
   <mat-icon class="icon_Nav">person_outline</mat-icon>
     My Profil
  </ng-template>
  <app-my-profil></app-my-profil>
  </mat-tab>
 </mat-tab-group>
```

Here is the ts code of my component 'myprofil', you should know that the html for the component is displaying correctly :

```
export class MyProfilComponent implements OnInit {
public imageResult: any;
img: HTMLImageElement;
username:string;

private userProfil: UserRegister ;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
private router: Router,
private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
private repo: RepositoryService,
private alertService: AlertService) { }

ngOnInit() {
 this.img = document.getElementById('imageProfil') as HTMLImageElement;
this.loadImageProfil();
this.loadProfil();
 }
//Load the user Image, if not found, assign empty Avatar to the image
loadImageProfil(): void {
this.repo.getData('api/Image')
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.imageResult = res;
    this.img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + this.imageResult;
  },
    error => {
      this.img.src = "../../../assets/avatar.png";
    });
 }
//Load the profil of the user and assign the values to the form
 loadProfil(): void {
  this.repo.getData('api/Profil')
   .subscribe((res :UserRegister) => {
     this.userProfil=res;
    this.username=this.userProfil.username;
    console.log(this.userProfil.username);
  },
    error => {
      this.alertService.error(error);
    });
  }
```

The last piece of code is where the troubles are. The lines where the source of the image is initialized and the one where I affect the username are causing troubles. They are not initialized and throw a NUllReferenceException. I guess the html is not "active" but as I'm very new to Angular (only 2 days), I'm still trying to figure some things out. If someone has some time to answer or just look, I would appreciate.

Have a nice day !

Lio

Comment: Where does your profile image come from in your app? Is it in the template for your `MyProfilComponent`? If so, you should rather use `@ViewChild()` instead of searching the DOM for it. Also, the `OnInit` hook runs before the template is rendered. If the image is in your template, you will need to put the code to manipulate the image in the `AfterViewInit` hook instead.

Comment: The image comes either from my API (it works fine) or in my folder image, yeah it's the template for myProfilComponent :) Ok thanks for your advices, I'll try that !

Comment: Where should I put ViewChild? It seems like it does not work

Comment: You can use `@ViewChild()` to get a reference to an item in your template https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/. You shouldn't need to even do that though. Since the image is in your template, why are you not just storing the image source as a property on your component and using that variable in your template instead of trying to get a reference to your image and setting that property in your component class?